# SYSTIN & AUXTIN temperatures: Is it normal?

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard, sensors

Here is my hardware configuration:

- Mainboard: B550M-HDV
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700G

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3

When I run sensors :

```sh
stulluk ~ $  sensors
nct6793-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                   752.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                     1.87 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                     3.46 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                     3.39 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                   240.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                   120.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                   904.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                     3.46 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                     3.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                     1.84 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                  168.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                  120.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                    1.87 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                    1.70 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                  184.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  2532 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                +120.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +31.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:               +111.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:               +111.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:               +111.0°C    sensor = thermistor
SMBUSMASTER 0:          +78.5°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            OK
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +42.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

amdgpu-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      912.00 mV 
vddnb:         1.02 V  
edge:         +45.0°C  
power1:        2.00 mW 

stulluk ~ $
```

Are these SYSTIN or AUXTIN temperatures normal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These temperatures don't make sense, or your case would have melted
down by now.

These are most likely for AUX temp sensors which you don't have or are
not connected.
Not all motherboards have all sensors, but this doesn't stop the software
from looking for them, so not finding real values.

You may ignore these numbers (unless you do see smoke coming out).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I am using this PC for about 6 months now, and it just run OK. No abnormal shutdowns or hangs. I guess it is wrong readings as you commented, so I will ignore until I find a good infrared thermometer :)

Comment: Done, thank you.